# Excel: How to add leading zero to string of numbers separated by comma, if the number is less than 8 digits?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I used `=IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)` to concatenate a string of associated SKUs across multiple rows into one cell. The problem is some of the SKUs start with 0, and this got removed with the formula. (Also, some of the rows are showing up as error cells with the red text and fill. The error message says they are a number being stored as text. But it's not like that with every one, and I don't know why.)

All the SKUs have 8 digits, so the incorrect ones will have 7 digits. For example:

Looks like: 4286000,4286800,4310001,4310801,14872001,14872801,14877001,14877801

Should be: 04286000,04286800,04310001,04310801,14872001,14872801,14877001,14877801

I tried the `=TEXT` function, and got a funny (wrong) result. For example, in a string where all six SKUs need a leading zero, I added 48 zeros in the format_text section of the function, with commas after every 8 zeros. It put the commas in every three digits, basically outputting as a large single number.

Is this something that can be solved with formulas, or does it require VBA?

Comment: `=IF(A2=A1,C1&",","")&TEXT(B2,"00000000")`

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the cell formatting to a custom 00000000 if it's a visual thing.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to tigeravatar's comment which will return a string instead of a number but will have the lead zero:

```
=RIGHT("00000000"&B2,8)

or

=RIGHT("00000000"&MAX(len(B2),8))
```

Basically it adds 8 zeros to the front then takes the last 8 characters.  Or in the case of the second formula it will take a minimum of 8 characters and a maximum of the length of what is already in the cell.  If you know you only have a minimum of 7 characters, then you could just add 1 zero.

Alternatively you could add the zeros using a REPT function:

```
=REPT("0",MAX(8-LEN(B2),0))&B2
```

The max is in there in case you have a number longer which would wind up with a negative value for REPT.  In that case, MAX would return 0 instead avoiding the error with REPT.  The result of this formula is also a string.

If you want to see a leading zero, but keep the cell value as a number, then you would need to apply custom formatting to the cell.  Just remember though the zero is not really there if you go that route, the cell is just displaying things as 8 digits long.